# Extracting positions 1 to 11 and position 13 from a 15-digit number/string in Oracle

Tags: oracle, substring

I have a 15-digit number that needs to be stored in an Oracle table either as a number or as a text.

1. Will I be able to select records from the table based on the field ("Positions 1 thru 11" + "Position 13")? 
   Example: If the data is 12345678901**2**3**45**, I need to select rows from the table to extract all rows that contain value "12345678901**3**" in that field.
2. Can an index be created in Oracle to ensure the above query performs as good as a normal select query on the entire data field.

Comment: If the field is stored as a string, then this is just `WHERE field >= '123456789013'` and lexicographical ordering that takes place on strings will bring back what you need. If it's stored as a number, you would have to CAST which would slow it down. I can't speak to indexing that would help speed up a lexicographical sort, but I think it would be reasonably fast right out of the box.

Comment: What does this field represent? Is it really a number or a string? Do those positions ( 1-11, 13 ) have significance?

Comment: If substrings have meaning, then you should store as a string. It would be quite exceptional that the 13th digit of a 15 digit *number* to have any particular meaning as a `number`. Then, depending on your database version, you can have a virtual column that extracts just positions 1-11 and 13 and concatenates these, or have a function index on this string manipulation on the stored data, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the column in text then something like this should solve your problem. Use the first if you need to query separately otherwise if you want to query on first eleven and thirteenth use the last example.

```
create index ix_firsteleven on TABLE (substr(COL, 1, 11))
create index ix_thrirteenth on TABLE (substr(COL, 13, 1))
```

or

```
create index ix_concatstr on TABLE (substr(COL, 1, 11) || substr(col_name, 13, 1))
```